# After a PUT Request a GET Request returns HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, web-services

i have a very strange problem.

I got a PUT method in my controller that it works, when the client call that method, the resource is edited in DB and a OK response is sent to the client.
After that if the client sends a GET request on the same controller, the server responds with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Verb</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request verb is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

By enabling debug mode, my get method is not called so it is managed all internally by .Net Core.

Here are the strange things:
If I put a breakpoint inside the Put method, the Get methods works!

If I change the Put method into a Post method everythings works!

If I wait circa a minute after the Put request to make the Get, everythings works!

If I do the same operations in Postman everything works!

I suspect that behind this strange behavior there is some configuration of Net core to set, but I tried different things like enabling cors or ignoring the anti forgery token but they did not works for me. Any suggestion?

Here is my Controller class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ServerMobile.Controllers.Utilities;
using ServerMobile.Data;
using ServerMobile.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ServerMobile.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class MatchController : ControllerBase
    {
        private DataContext context;

        public MatchController(DataContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

    //GET: api/match/mymatches/
    [HttpGet("mymatches")]
    public ActionResult MyMatches()
    {
        string userNickname = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        List<Match> matches = context.Matches.Where(m => !m.Ended && (m.PlayerGuest.Nickname.Equals(userNickname) || m.PlayerHost.Nickname.Equals(userNickname))).ToList();
        if (matches.Count == 0)
            return Ok(new ResponseContainer<List<Match>>() { Response = matches, Error = "No matches found" });
        return Ok(new ResponseContainer<List<Match>>() { Response = matches });
    }

    //PUT: api/match/JoinMatch/:matchId:/
    [HttpPut("JoinMatch/{matchId}")]
    public ActionResult JoinMatch(Guid matchId)
    {
        string nickGuest = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        Match match = context.Matches.Where(m => m.Id.Equals(matchId)).First();
        if (match == null)
            return NotFound(new ResponseContainer<List<Match>>() { Error = "There is no match with that Id" });
        if (match.PlayerGuest != null)
            return Conflict(new ResponseContainer<List<Match>>() { Error = "The match is no more available" });
        Player guest = context.Players.Find(nickGuest);
        if (guest == null)
            return NotFound(new ResponseContainer<List<Match>>() { Error = "No player found" });
        match.JoinMatch(guest);
        match.PlayerGuest = guest;
        context.Update(match);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok(new ResponseContainer<Match>() { Response = match });
        }

    }
}
```

And here the Configure in the Startup class:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

       // app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Comment: It seems probable to me that you're either a) calling the wrong endpoint or b) using the wrong verb. That it works at all is perplexing.

Comment: No no, the same call is done before the put and has not problem.

Comment: Is it on IIS? Or Local?

Comment: Could there be a mistake in the code you're using to call it?

Comment: Usually .NET core enable `WebDAVModule` which sometimes conflict with `PUT` and `DELETE` method. So you may try to disable that by `<remove name="WebDAVModule" />` on your IIS configuration.

Comment: @Jaeger it's a really interesting problem, i would suggest you use await async process.```[HttpGet("mymatches")]public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Match>>> MyMatches()```

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I don't have a web.config file in my project, can I add it manually?

Comment: @PritomSarkar Tried to make async the method but didn't work:

Comment: @Jaeger do you mean that,your .net core(backend) is works in postman as expected,but when you try to from font-end, you are facing this issue?

Comment: @PritomSarkar Exactly! And the strangest thing is that if I put a breakpoint inside the PUT method everything works fine.

Comment: As it's dotnet core there shouldn't be any webconfig, you have to set manually on iis.

Comment: Ok @MdFaridUddinKiron, I'll try it!

Comment: Surely, even if doesn't work let us know the update. Problem has to be solve.

Comment: To be honest i did not understand if I added correctly the file. Some guides says that is enough to add the web.config file in the root of the project. Is there a way to verify if is added correctly?

Comment: Yes you could have a look [here in offical docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/modules?view=aspnetcore-5.0#module-removal)

Comment: The fact that I run the project from Visual studio with IIS Express could be different?

Comment: In that case it should work I believe